Apollo client cursor based using only first and last
I am using Apollo client (with react) to get result (graphQl + relay ), and server-side pagination
I have read that using cursor-based pagination is the most reliable way, so previously I was using offset, and now I want to move to the cursor based pagination
in fact, I cannot depend on the cursor itself (using after) since sometimes I need to jump directly to the latest page, so I managed that depending on:
after = null, and used first = total edges and used last to get only the needed data
    const handlePagination = () => {
    const last = Math.min(pagination.pageSize, totalEdges - (pagination.pageIndex * pagination.pageSize));
    refetch({
      after: null,
      first: (pagination.pageIndex + 1) * (pagination.pageSize),
      last: last || pagination.pageSize,
      nameContains: searchInputRef.current,
    });
  };

so here there is no real dependence on the cursor itself, so my question:
1- Is that considered to be cursor-based, or am I re-doing the offset within cursor variables.
2- Is it better to use cursors (after and before) and only in the case of the last page I should use the first and last variables?

The same if there is a "refresh" button, in this case what should "before" or "after" parameters be ?
